# pull apache beam from github compile error

Tags: maven, apache-beam

I am new to Apache beam, I download latest source code from github and compile runner module under path : 

`../beam/runners`

with command : mvn package and it prints the exception like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY021.jpg)

`Apache Beam :: Runners :: Core Construction Java ... FAILURE`

Does anyone have some ideas with this ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Balajee Venkatesh
Here are my compile steps:

1. cd beam-master
2. mvn compile
3. wait compile finish

The first time I execute mvn compile command and met the exception shown above was under path beam-master/runners. After I changing compiling path to beam-master everything goes well .

And may I ask are you trying to compile the whole project to load it to your IDE ?
If so , I  suggest using IDEA with 'File'->'import from existing source'  instead of executing 'mvn compile' command .

If you try to use IDEA import beam , you can just remove/comment error messages in ${project_loc:beam-parent/pom.xml}  like ：

```
  <!-- <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <reports>
          <report>dependency-updates-report</report>
          <report>plugin-updates-report</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
  </plugin>-->
```

and, replace this maven plugins version the same as your mvn -version .

```
  <!-- Rename the artifact produced by the Apache parent's
         source release. -->
     <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>**3.3.3**</version>  
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>source-release-assembly</id>
          <configuration>
            <finalName>apache-beam-${project.version}</finalName>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

By the way , my maven version is 3.3.3 . You can also check out if the pom.xml's  maven version incompatible with your local mvn -version .

Here is my mvn compile path :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FkGX.png)

Answer (score 0):

After I changing my compiling path to main path every module compiled success.

Comment: How to change the compilation path? Could you please make me understand precisely? I'm facing similar issues while installing latest Apache Beam project from GitHub. @kylin

Comment: Hi, the first time my compile path is under ./runners/ ， After I changing compile path to ./runners parent path every module compiled success .

Comment: How did you change the compilation path? I would feel privileged if you share any supportive steps or snapshots for the same.

Comment: is this `${project_loc:beam-parent/runners}` you are talking about? I'm using the same as base directory while setting the run-configurations.